# Feature proposal : Links to recent post/answers

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

We should have a little list appended to `nav.navigation > ol.nav-links` on the left, with links to our recent posts and aswers (even the most recent/active favorites, why not ?).
If not connected there could be just some links corresponding to the `session` and `cookie` content, or just a button to sign up/log in.
These links could also indicate new activity with a little notification marker.

I think this is clear enough for such a simple (yet useful) feature.

Comment: Why? All of this is already available on the profile page. I don’t need to see these posts all the time. I don’t want to see three columns of post links (the HNQ list and whichever list I’m currently looking for, in addition to your feature).

Comment: Personally I don't like having to go to my profile page to fetch the last question/answer I posted. (In case I found an answer/more info after looking again -google won't give you any useful information until you post a duplicate/wrong answer on SO- and I want to edit my post/answer)

Comment: If you are still doing research after publishing a post (either a question or an answer), I'd advise to keep the tabs with those posts open. That's a more useful workflow.

Comment: For the "new activity" indicator in the links, not clear what new activity you'd like this notification marker that's not already covered by the notification system.

Comment: I meant just some way to indicate there is a new answer/comment to our post, or a new comment to our answer - (about any action that would trigger a notification in the `recent inbox messages`)

Comment: If you alredy have a notification in your inbox... what do you need another indicator/marker/link for? You already have a one click solution to go to your post in those cases.

Comment: If there is no notification, there is no easy one-click return.

However indeed, just keeping the tab open works. I'm just that kind of person that opens to many tabs...

Comment: Are you regularly not getting notifications? That might be a bug.

Comment: @BSMP I get them. This was not the problem ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably be able to do this in the future with [saved custom question lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/323179) by putting specific things (`user:me` for one's own posts and `infavorites:mine` for one's favorite questions) in the "custom search" box:

> [image]

It will then appear in the sidebar under "shortcuts":

> [image]

This feature is supposed to be introduced sometime this month (November) the [last I heard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313940/323179). They're also planning to add notifications in December.